# Resizing a two dimensional Array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, resize

How can I resize the two dimensional array size without affecting its value?

Comment: What do you mean by "affecting its value"?

Comment: I mean the values store in the array will not be lost.

Comment: As a side note, observe that "resizing" arrays isn't really possible, and always involves creating a new array and copying the data. Avoid doing it too much...

Answer (score 7):

<s>Use `ReDim` with the `Preserve` modifier. VB.NET will make sure the original values are untouched.</s> **Didn't read the documentation right.** `ReDim Preserve` will only allow you to change the length of the last dimension of the array.

You need to allocate a new array (with the correct size) and manually copy the elements from the first array to the second.

Comment: Never realized redim was limited to the last dimension, uh. Guess Array.Copy will get some attention too.

Answer (score 4):

As Adam said, you can't resize 2D arrays dynamically. You can easily copy the existing array into a bigger one like so:

```
Dim smaller(1, 1) As Byte
Dim bigger(2, 2) As Byte
Array.Copy(smaller, bigger, smaller.length)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `array.resize` if you are on .net 2 framework or above.

For example:

```
Dim MyArray() as string
Array.Resize(myarray,12)
```

Comment: From the documentation, the array parameter is "The one-dimensional, zero-based array to resize". OP explicit asked about 2D arrays.